# Problema com nested form has_many through utilizando formulario dinamico

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou com o seguinte problema em um formulário utilizando has_many through.

Tenho um cadastro onde eu criou formulários dinamicos. Esses formulários dinamicos são inseridos em uma outra tela.

Estou com dificuldade no controller onde eu insiro esses fomulários e na view que faço a inserção.

Appointments -> onde posso ter muito formularios dinamicos (record_forms)
Record_Forms -> cadastro dos formulários dinamicos
Record_Form_Fields -> campos do formulario dinamico
Appointment_Record_Forms -> tabela para relacionamento entre Appointments e Record_Forms

**Schema**

```
create_table "appointment_record_forms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "appointment_id", limit: 4
    t.integer  "record_form_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.text     "properties",     limit: 65535
  end

  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "duration",         limit: 255
    t.date     "appointment_date"
    t.integer  "patient_id",       limit: 4
    t.integer  "doctor_id",        limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  end

  create_table "record_form_fields", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",           limit: 255
    t.string   "field_type",     limit: 255
    t.boolean  "required"
    t.integer  "record_form_id", limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "record_forms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

**Models**

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor

  has_many   :appointment_record_forms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :record_forms, through: :appointment_record_forms
  has_many :record_form_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for  :appointment_record_forms, allow_destroy: true
 end

class AppointmentRecordForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :record_form

  serialize :properties, Hash

  def validate_properties
    record_form.record_form_fields.each do |record_form_field|
      if record_form_field.required? && properties[record_form_field.name].blank?
        errors.add record_form_field.name, "must not be blank"
      end
    end
  end
end

class RecordForm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :record_form_fields

    has_many :appointment_record_forms, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :appointments, through: :appointment_record_forms

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :record_form_fields, allow_destroy: true

end

class RecordFormField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record_form
end

**Controller**


class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

.
.
.
def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:duration, :appointment_date, :patient_id, :doctor_id,
                                           :record_form_ids, :appointment_form_ids
          )
    end
end
```

**View**

*Appointments/_form.html.erb*

```
<!-- onde escolho um formulario dinamico e clico para inseri-lo -->

...
<%= f.fields_for :appointment_record_forms do |builder| %>
    <%= f.select_tag :record_form_id, options_from_collection_for_select(RecordForm.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= render 'appointment_record_form_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", f, :appointment_record_forms %>
....
```

**Partial**

*Appointments/_appointment_record_form_fields.html.br*

```
<!-- Aqui é onde eu carrego os campos do formulario dinamico e salvo e busco os valores desses campos atraves do hash 'properties' --> 

 <fieldset>  
  <%= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@appointment_record_forms.properties) do    |builder| %>
    <% @appointment_record_forms.record_form.record_form_fields.each do |record_form_field| %>

      <%= render "appointments/fields/#{record_form_field.field_type}", record_form_field: record_form_field, f: builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Atualmente ao rodar a aplicação esta com o erro:

```
undefined method `properties' for :appointment_record_forms:Symbol
```

Gostaria de saber como eu devo fazer no controller do appointment para receber a associação, na view para inserir o formulario dinamico e Partial para listar salvar os registro no hash e mostrar os campos do formulario corretamente.

Desde de já agradeço se alguem poder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

#### primeiro

> ```
> class RecordForm < ActiveRecord::Base
>     has_many :record_form_fields
>
>     has_many :appointment_record_forms, dependent: :destroy
>     has_many :appointments, through: :appointment_record_forms
>
>     accepts_nested_attributes_for :record_form_fields, allow_destroy: true
> ```
>
> você faz accepts_nested de `record_form_fields` e não `appointment_record_forms`
>
> ```
> end
> ```

#### segundo

> ```
> <%= f.fields_for :appointment_record_forms do |builder| %>
> ```
>
> você chama por `appointment_record_forms` sem ter `accepts_nested`
>
> ```
>     <%= f.select_tag :record_form_id, options_from_collection_for_select(RecordForm.all, :id, :name) %>
>
>     <%= render 'appointment_record_form_fields', f: builder %>
>
>     <% end %>
>     <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", f, :appointment_record_forms %>
> ....
> ```

não acho que serializando o hash deveria ser instanciando dessa maneira. Eu faço algo parecido com isso baixo

```
= form_for @widget do |f|
  = f.fields_for :options, OpenStruct.new(f.object.options || {}) do |f2|
    = f2.text_field :axis_y
    = f2.text_field :axis_x
    = f2.text_field :unit
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002963/how-to-edit-a-rails-serialized-field-in-a-form

O que tem aqui dentro? `@appointment_record_forms.properties`

#### terceiro e mais importante, comece em baby-steps.

Faça primeiro a view `/_appointment_record_form_fields.html.br` funcionar sem esses nested form todos. Comente todo resto deixando os `renders` ou coloque isso abaixo no `views/appoiment..../new` sem o resto do forms e fields_for

```
<%= form_for AppointmentRecordForm.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(AppointmentRecordForm.new.properties || {} ) do    |ff| %>
     <%= ff.text_field :coluna_do_properties_1 %>
     <%= ff.text_field :coluna_do_properties_2 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```